# can't compile witn webpack-encore, the webpack requires version ^8.0.0

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

WARNING   Webpack Encore requires version ^8.0.0 of sass-loader, but your version (7.3.1) is too old. The related feature will probably *not* work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite clear in itself, you installed a version of sass-loader too old.
You just have to replace it.

```
yarn remove sass-loader
yarn add sass-loader@^8.0.0
```